# Get MAX value from Doctrine ORM and show it using AbstractCrudController

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity with following fields: `id`, `name`, `updatedAt`.

I am using `AbstractCrudController` and on its index page I would like to show: `name`, `updatedAt` and `MAX(updatedAt)`.

How can I do that? `Doctrine` does not seem to support aggregate functions so looks like I have to do it on a controller level, right? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $builder = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);

    return $builder->addSelect('(SELECT MAX(roles.updatedAt) FROM App\Entity\Roles roles) AS lastUpdatedAt');
}
```

Result SQL query works alright:

```
SELECT r0_.id AS id_0, r0_.name AS name_1, r0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6
     , (SELECT MAX(r1_.updated_at) AS sclr_8 FROM roles r1_) AS sclr_7 
FROM roles r0_
```

But I am getting following error:

> Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write the property path as "[id]" instead.

Comment: https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/5800